# Как реализовать такой фон

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Недавно "прогуливаясь" по интернету нашел такой сайт [Приватный чит для DOTA 2](http://umbrella-cheats.ru/?tag=reshuege&ext-uniq-id=1jf54rZ5u8q1q82uR27u2in55S&yclid=7788509499929427918), вы не подумайте игра меня не интересует, меня заинтересовал фон приведенного сайта *(надеюсь вы понимаете, что я говорю не о картинке)*, если точнее как можно его реализовать и какими технологиями воспользоваться.
 P.S. По причине того, что я как сказано выше не знаю какими языками или фреймворками воспользоваться,теги на вопрос ставлю неточные

Comment: @cedev-sk html5, css3, графика canvas (создается с помощью js)  скорее всего это все технологии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться этой библиотекой:
[Particle.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/)